# How to add an Vector Tile Service to ArcMap (ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vector-tiles

ESRI produces and provides access to several styled vector tile services (https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/basemap-styles/ ), but I'm having trouble adding those to ArcMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcMap, especially 10.5.1, is older technology. It does not support Vector Tile basemap services.

Quoting the [Knowlege Base](https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/faq-is-it-possible-to-use-esri-vector-basemaps-in-arcma-000024586) article:

> No, it is not possible to add or use Esri vector basemaps in ArcMap. Esri vector basemaps are delivered as vector tiles (PBF format), rendered client-side, and based on a style file that is delivered with the vector tiles. ArcMap does not support vector tiles.